# Trigger code segments for ROS_DEBUG only

Tags: ros, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm wondering if there's a way to do the following in C++:

```
if(<my logger level is set to ROS_DEBUG>) 
{
  //execute a costly code block that I don't want to do for the sake of efficiency
  //unless my logger level is set to ROS_DEBUG.  
  ROS_DEBUG_STREAM("Some output based on the computation");
}
```

I need to do some computation to get useful output in DEBUG mode, but I don't want to do that computation in normal operation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10976/trigger-code-segments-for-ros_debug-only/) by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2031 on 2011-08-22

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a little bit of a hack but would have the desired effect.

```
string costly_method_wrapper()
{
//Costly stuff in here
return std::string(); // or real debugging info here.
}
ROS_DEBUG_STREAM("my output is " << costly_method_wrapper() << " other debug info");
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) on 2011-08-24**:
I was hoping for something slightly more elegant, but this indeed will do.